# How can I limit the writable space in hyperref's TextFields?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, forms

I'm creating a pdf form using `hyperref`. After it has been filled-out, the form will be printed. I'm looking for a way to prevent the user from entering more characters into a TextField than will be seen on the print-out. The `maxlen` option is not really what I'm looking for - it's more about space than number of characters.

Incidentally, I do get some of the desired results when using the `multiline=true` option, at least in Adobe Reader 9 (which will be used): entered text breaks at the visual end of the TextField. Sadly, the number of rows increases instead. So I'm stuck with the same problem - only now it's vertically, not horizontally.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer! `Hyperref` supports the `donotscroll=true` option, which limits the input to the printable area. Also works for `multiline=true` fields.

Example: `\TextField[donotscroll=true]{This field will not expand}`